# 553 sorry, Authentication failed or timed out. Please do get messages first to authenticate yourself.(#4.4.3)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail using Java Mail API but I am not able to send the mail because following error is occuring

```
553 sorry, Authentication failed or timed out. Please do get messages first to authenticate yourself.(#4.4.3)
```

I am not able to understand where the problem is occuring or is there any special setting for rediff ?
I googled it but didn't find a solution .Please help me to rectify it

here is my code

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;

import java.util.Properties;


public class TestMail {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       new TestMail().test();
    }

    public void test() throws Exception{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.rediffmailpro.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
       // props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");


        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        // uncomment for debugging infos to stdout
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setContent("This is a test", "text/plain");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxxxxxxxxx"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
             new InternetAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"));

        transport.connect();
       transport.sendMessage(message,
            message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
        //Transport.send(message);

    }

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           String username = "xxxxxxxxx";
           String password = "xxxxxxxx";
           return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put whole debug trace of connecting with SMTP server and all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this Error by changing

```
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
```

to

```
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

In Specfictions of JavaMail API,It is specified that All Properties must be set as String.Here is the link 
https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

To prevent being used to send out SPAM most SMTP servers demand some kind of authentication when you try to use them to relay mail (i.e. send mail to other servers).

This can be a user and password being supplied when connecting to the server. Other servers - and this seems to be the case here - demand that you connect them using POP3 or IMAP first (where you have to send authentication). They remember that your IP address was successfully used for an authenticated connection, and allow SMTP relay requests for a certain time after that.

One way to check wenther this is the case here is to use your mail programm to get your mail, then immediately after that run your program from the same machine (or at least over the same internet connection) to send the mail.

If this works, you'd either have to make a POP3 connection in your application before sending out mail, or talk to your mail provider whether there are other ways to authenticate an SMTP connection.